# Can I add hard-coded ComboBoxItems via a Style?

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I have a small app where the same ComboBox appears in multiple places and it always has the same set of items.  Instead of doing this every time I use the combo box:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1" Tag="1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="5" Tag="5" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="10" Tag="10" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="50" Tag="50" />
</ComboBox>
```

I was thinking it'd be better to make the items part of a Style that I could apply to each ComboBox.  Does anyone know how to make it work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method I often use for ComboBoxes with identical item lists is to create a static class with a collection property containing the Items, then bind the `ItemsSource` to this static property

```
public static class StaticLists
{
    public static List<int> MyList { get; private set; }

    static Lists()
    {
        MyList = LoadSomeList();
    }
}
```

and

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:StaticLists.MyList}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up something similar to this using a dictionary of ints to strings (LookupDictionaries.TheItems) and then I used a style to do the binding:  <data:LookupDictionaries x:Key="Lookups" />, <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lookups}, Path=TheItems}" />

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what Rachel suggested, if you wanted to keep it all XAML, you could put your items (not ComboBoxItems, but the backing data item) into a Resource and then bind to that resource.